How to find the longest subsequence containing all vowels in order in a string in Python?
I am working on a problem where I need to find the length of the longest subsequence in a given string that contains all the vowels (a, e, i, o, u) in order and no vowels out of order. The vowels can repeat, but they must be in the correct order.
For example:

The string aeiaaioaaaaeiiiiouuuooaauuaeiu should return 13 because the longest valid subsequence is aaaaeiiiiouuu which has length 13.
The string aeiooou should return 7 because the longest valid subsequence is aeiooou which has length 7.
The string aaeeiioouu should return 10 because the longest valid subsequence is aaeeiioouu which has length 10.
The string aeiaaiooaauua should return 0 because it does not contain all vowels in order.

My code so far:
def normalize_string(s):
    normalized = []
    previous_char = ''
    char_count = 0

    for char in s:
        if char in "aeiou":
            if char != previous_char:
                if previous_char != '':
                    counts[previous_char] = max(counts[previous_char], char_count)
                normalized.append(char)
                char_count = 1
            else:
                char_count += 1
        previous_char = char

    if previous_char in "aeiou":
        counts[previous_char] = max(counts[previous_char], char_count)

    return ''.join(normalized), counts

def longestVowelSubsequence(s):
    normalized, counts = normalize_string(s)
    
    dp = [0] * 5  # dp array to keep track of the longest subsequence ending at each vowel

    for char in normalized:
        if char == 'a':
            dp[0] += counts[char]
        elif char == 'e' and dp[0] > 0:
            dp[1] = max(dp[1], dp[0] + counts[char])
        elif char == 'i' and dp[1] > 0:
            dp[2] = max(dp[2], dp[1] + counts[char])
        elif char == 'o' and dp[2] > 0:
            dp[3] = max(dp[3], dp[2] + counts[char])
        elif char == 'u' and dp[3] > 0:
            dp[4] = max(dp[4], dp[3] + counts[char])

    return dp[4]

# Example tests
print(longestVowelSubsequence("aeiaaioaaaaeiiiiouuuooaauuaeiu"))  # Should return 13
print(longestVowelSubsequence("aeiooou"))  # Should return 7
print(longestVowelSubsequence("aaeeiioouu"))  # Should return 10
print(longestVowelSubsequence("aeiaaiooaauua"))  # Should return 0


Is there a reason you are not simply using a regular expression? subsequences = re.findall(r'a+e+i+o+u+', s)

notice that str supports inequalities and the sequence of vowels is ordered. You could use it to build group of (ordered) characters each starting with a and then apply a "completeness" condition (representing all the voewels)

Strings supports a natural ordering, so implementation of the <, <=, >, >= relations are inbuilt.
Idea: Form groups which satisfy the ordering condition, start with a and have made of 5 distinct characters.
def longest_vowel_subsequence(text:str) -> int:
    vowels = "aeiou"
    
    seq = ''
    tmp_seq = ''
    last_vowel = 'a'
    for char in text:
        # make ordered groups
        if char >= last_vowel:
            tmp_seq += char
            last_vowel = char
        else:
            # check completeness of the group and update
            if len(set(tmp_seq)) == len(vowels):
                seq = max(seq, tmp_seq, key=len)
    
            # reset defaults for the next group
            last_vowel = 'a'
            tmp_seq = (last_vowel if char == last_vowel else '')
    else:
        # check result last iteration
        if len(set(tmp_seq)) == len(vowels):
            seq = max(seq, tmp_seq, key=len)
    
    # display formatted info
    print(f"length max seq {len(seq)}: '{seq}'")

    return len(seq)


texts = (
    "aeiaaioaaaaeiiiiouuuooaauuaeiu",  # Should return 13
    "aeiooou",  # Should return 7
    "aaeeiioouu",  # Should return 10
    "aeiaaiooaauua",  # Should return 0
)

for text in texts:
    longest_vowel_subsequence(text)

Output
length max seq 13: 'aaaaeiiiiouuu'
length max seq 7: 'aeiooou'
length max seq 10: 'aaeeiioouu'
length max seq 0: ''

